# How to verify that a method called with an instance of any subtype of the given interface

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I would like the check whether a method is called with an instance of a given interface.

The following cannot verify that the method is called with an instance of any implementation of `SomeInterface`

```
Mockito.verify(objectToBeTested).myMethod(Mockito.any(SomeInterface.class));
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand the value of this assertion. In terms of behavior it verifies very fine implementation details.

Comment: I am using [guava's eventbus](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.java) which can post `Object`. I have to check the type of the event.

Comment: I understand. But that is rather brittle as assertion. The content of the transmitted event is not checked. Personally I would perform a more complete assertion on it or I would favor integration test.

Answer (score 1):

Create a captor which can capture any instance of the given class or interface, then check that the captured instance is of the expected type. Also you have to take care of multiple invocations if necessary.

```
ArgumentCaptor<SomeInterface> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SomeInterface.class);
Mockito.verify(objectToBeTested).myMethod(captor.capture());

assertThat(captor.getValue(), Matchers.instanceOf(SomeInterface.class));
```